# Configuring and connect to Neo4j

Tags: python, ubuntu, graph, neo4j

Dears,

When I'm trying to execute my python code I encountered the following error **"No module named Neo4j"**.
I then installed the neo4j. Then I found that I have to configure and to connect to Neo4j. When I run the `cypher-sehll` in the terminal command I found this error **"The server does not support any of the protocol versions supported by this driver. Ensure that you are using driver and server that are compatible with one another".**

Any idea Please

Thanks

Comment: Please also post your code. Thanks.

Comment: Neo4J installed version? Are you sure Neo4J instance is running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.